# Python multiple conditions with if else Statement? [SOLVED CASE]

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
name = input("set name: ")
pPassWord= input("Set password: ")

if not (name == "James"):
    print("Name was wrong")
    if not (pPassWord == "Example"):
        print("Password was wrong")
    else:
    print("Name and password is wrong")
else:
    print("Name and password is right ! :) ")
```

What is wrong?

If i set wrong name = different  "James"

console printer is

```
Name was wrong 
Set Password:
```

I want only

```
Name was wrong
```

Comment: Your indentation is not legal python. Please fix.

Comment: You want to check if the name is right, then only you want to input the password

Comment: Its `if name != 'James'`. And and "else" is treated as "otherwise". If you want to consider an alternative condition, use "elif"

Comment: The check of "password" is not in the `else:` so it happens no matter what was the "name".

Answer (score 2):

Try  this:

```
name = input("set name: ")

if not (name== "James"):
    print("Name was wrong")
    return #exit the function if something not valid

pPassWord= input("Set password: ")
if not (pPassWord== "Example"):
    print("Password was wrong")
    return
else:
    print("Name and password is right ! :) ")
```

Comment: I really liked your solution - but it doesn't address the 4th case explicitly i.e. `print("Name and password is wrong")`

Comment: How this "return" working? my editor says "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function" 

Outside? how?

Comment: You have to define it in a function

Answer (score 2):

```
name = input("set name: ")
pPassWord= input("Set password: ")

if (name != "James") & (pPassWord != "Example"):
    print("Name and password is wrong")
elif name != "James":
    print("Name was wrong")
elif pPassWord != "Example":
    print("Password was wrong") 
else:
    print("Name and password is right ! :) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong, please try the following:

```
if not (name== "James"):
    print("Name was wrong")
    if not (pPassWord== "Example"): // due to the indentation, this now belongs to the first if-clause
        print("Password was wrong")
    else:
        print("Name and password is wrong")
else:
    print("Name and password is right ! :) ")
```

Comment: @MrFuppes: I've adapted my answer accordingly (I hope :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

You set two input line after each other at the top of your script. if you don't want second input will be asked when name is wrong, you have to do sth like this:

```
name = input("set name: ")
if not name == "James":
    print("Name was wrong")
else:
    pPassWord = input("Set password: ")
    if not pPassWord == "Example":
        print("Password was wrong")
    else:
        print("Name and password is right ! :) ")
```

please consider priority in using 'if, elif and else'. This link maybe helps for extra info.:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else

Good Luck!

Comment: Right. This working with this case. Thank you @MKia! :)